# Computing a MAC for a DESFire file read

Tags: c#, cryptography, mifare, des

I am  being driven mildly mad by this. I am trying to validate a MAC code produced by a read of data from a DESFire card. After authentication I have:

```
RNDA: 174067B263D4A2FB
RNDB: 28556156579E6F8D
```

Which makes a session key of 174067B228556156. I do a read of a file that contains the ASCII 'Hello'. The resultant data is:

48656C6C6F9E34BA18 which makes the MAC 9E34BA18. I cannot reproduce it. My C# code is below. It produces a MAC of 826C10B4DD1F3632 neither top nor bottom 32-bits are the desired MAC.

```
        byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F}; // Hello
        var key16 = Slicer.FromHexToBytes(SessionKey + SessionKey);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            key16[i] = (byte)(key16[i] & 0xfe); // bottom bit contains version so set it to 0
        }
        KeyParameter key = new DesParameters(key16);
        var mac = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.MacUtilities.GetMac("DESEDEISO9797ALG1MACWITHISO7816-4PADDING");
        mac = new CbcBlockCipherMac(new DesEdeEngine(), 64, new ZeroBytePadding());
        mac.Init(key);

        mac.BlockUpdate(data, 0, data.Length);

        byte[] outBytes = new byte[mac.GetMacSize()];
        mac.DoFinal(outBytes, 0);
        Debug.Print(outBytes);
```

Just doubling up the session key seems like a guess but I have seen it mentioned in several places. I hope I am on the right track, can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try looking at ARP table from cmd.exe >ARP -A.  The mac is returned from the ARP (ping response) and is stored in the ARP table.  It will stay in table for about an hour before being removed.  The MAC is built into the Ethernet interface an is unique and cannot change.

Comment: @jdweng there is a difference between *media access control* and *Message Authentication Code*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Can you unlock card using windows and then read/write card in c#?  Card have different modes (like 8,16,32,64).  So I always recommend first getting c# code reading and writing by unlocking in windows.  Then after you know the mode the card is using then unlock in c#.

Comment: @jdweng 'unlock the card using Windows'? What does that mean?

Comment: Use Window Explorer to browse card.  This will unlock card and verify the drivers are installed and check if card works.

Comment: The card works. I can do a full authentication. I am asking about generating a MAC code for the transaction.

Comment: Are you sure that your key is correctly calculated from rndA and rndB? Also why do you mask the Least Significant Bit ? Are you sure about the zero padding and the block size of 8 bytes? usually for aes it is 16

Comment: Looks like DESFire protocol is not public. You will need to reverse engineer it. There are others who have gone down this path before: https://github.com/miohtama/desfire

Comment: I have now solved this although not with this code. I was able to find some samples from a link in code pointed to by @HackSlash. It turns out the session key is dependant on the authentication key. The doubling I mention is correct if the authentication key is symmetric which it is for the default 0000.000 key - and which it wasn't in my example. I would be happy to award the bounty to HackSlash as his comment led me to the answer.

Comment: What do you think of the recently released by Mifare SDK TapLinx library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like DESFire protocol is not public. You will need to reverse engineer it. There are others who have gone down this path before. Take a look at this example project in Python: https://github.com/miohtama/desfire

I apologize that the only code I could find was in a different language. I am glad you were able to extract the logic you needed from it.

The solution you cited is:

> It turns out the session key is dependant on the authentication key.
> The doubling I mention is correct if the authentication key is
> symmetric which it is for the default 0000....000 key - and which it
> wasn't in my example.

Comment: @Rob Feel free to edit this answer to include the actual final code for others who follow in your footsteps.